# Create a white light spectrum or shaped rainbow in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I need to create a spectrum of white light or rainbow, in different shapes.

When I use [this method](http://art.vinayraikar.com/2008/01/illustrating-rainbow-with-tiled-clones.html) my clones are still the same color of the first.

Does any one have a better method or another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work good for me.

Are you sure that you're setting the "undefined" color ?
Setting "no color" doesn't work.

[image: like this]